# What does each line of this bash script do?

Tags: bash

I found an old past paper question with content not covered in my course. I hope I don't get examined with that but what does this bash script do? I know grep takes user input and outputs the line containing the input and echo just repeats the input and cat just displays the input. But I have on idea what this does as a whole. Any help please?

```
#!/bin/bash

outputFile=$1
for file in $(find -name '*txt' | grep data)
do
  echo $file >> $outputFile
  cat $file >> $outputFile
done
```

Comment: looks like it just combines the files.

Comment: It combines the files __unless__ the file names contain white space.  I hope that this code was not written by your course instructor.

Comment: http://explainshell.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Hash-bang the script to use bash

```
outputFile=$1
```

Set the variable named "outputFile" to the first parameter passed into the script. Running the script would look like `bash myScript.sh "/some/file/to/output.txt"`

```
for file in $(find -name '*txt' | grep data)
do
```

Loop through every file in this directory and it's subdirectories looking for a file that ends in with the characters "txt" and contains the characters "data" somewhere in the name. For each iteration of the for loop/file found, set the file name to the variable "file"

```
  echo $file >> $outputFile
```

Echo out/print the file name stored in the variable "file" to the outputFile

```
  cat $file >> $outputFile
```

Take the contents of the file and stick it in the outputFile.

```
done
```

End the For Loop

There's some issues with this script though. If $outputFile or $file have a space in their name or path, then it will fail. It's good practice to toss double quotes around variables like:

```
cat "$file" >> "$outputFile"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help kind sir!

Comment: The variable `file` will never have spaces in it because _word splitting_ is performed  previously on the line `for file in $(find -name '*txt' | grep data)`.

Comment: True, but after word splitting and glob expansion, the script may end up with a value for `$file` that is not a file, at which point `cat` will fail.

Comment: @kojiro Yes, that is the point.  To truly fix the problem, one has to start by fixing the `for file...` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The shebang. If this script is executable an invoked directly as in ./this_script or found in the PATH, it will be invoked with `/bin/bash`.

```
outputFile=$1
```

Assign the first argument to the name `outputFile`.

```
++ find -name '*txt'
```

Recursively list all files with a name ending in "txt". It would be more standard to include the path and write this as `find . -name '*.txt'`.

```
+ … | grep data
```

Filter the previous list of file names. Only list those containing the string "data" in their names. This pipe could be eliminated by writing `find . -name '*data*txt'`.

```
for file in $(find -name '*txt' | grep data)
```

For every *word* in the output of the `find | grep` pipeline, assign that word to the name `file` and run the loop. This can break down if any of the found names have whitespace or glob characters in them. It would be better to use `find`'s native `-exec` flag to handle this.

```
  echo $file >> $outputFile
```

Append the expansion of the variable "file" to a new or existing file at the path found by expanding `$outputFile`. If the former expansion starts with a dash, it could cause `echo` to treat it as an argument. If the latter expansion has whitespace or a glob character in it, this may cause an "ambiguous redirect" error. It would be better to quote the expansions, and use `printf` to avoid the argument edge-case to `echo`, as in `printf '%s\n' "$file" >> "$outputFile"`.

```
  cat $file >> $outputFile
```

Append the contents of the file found at the expansion of the variable "file" to the path found by expanding `$outputFile`, or cause another ambiguous redirect error. It would be better to quote the expansions, like `cat "$file" >> "$outputFile"`.

Assuming that none of the aforementioned expansion edge-cases were expected, it would be better to write this entire script like this:

```
find . -name '*data*txt' -print -exec cat {} \; >> "$1"
```

Comment: + 1.  The `find` command looks robust to me.  Was there some case for which you were expecting it not to work?

Comment: @John1024 the original `find | grep` command could fail if there is a file with newlines in its name.

Comment: Let me clarify: this command `find . -name '*data*txt' -print -exec cat {} \; >> "$1"` looks robust to me and yet it is introduced with the phrase _"Assuming that none of the aforementioned expansion edge-cases were expected"_.  I was wondering what those edge-cases were for that command?

Comment: @John1024 I meant that the original form has several things I consider to be bugs, but they could be intentional. My form would not reproduce those effects.